# How to access wordpress database?

Tags: database, wordpress, cpanel

I do have the access for the ftp account for this wordpress website and I need to access to its database.

Where can I find it? It doesn't have a cpanel cause when I try to access `www.sampleURL.com/cpanel` it shows:

> Not Found The requested URL /cpanel was not found on this server.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of [phpmyadmin-like](http://blog.primalskill.com/2-great-web-based-alternatives-to-phpmyadmin/) tools out there. You can get the login data by editing `wp-config.php` file from your wp root.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'd connect with the `mysql` client typically... you won't find the database with an FTP client.

Comment: where could I find the `mysql` since I can't access the cpanel. or it doesn't have any.

Comment: `mysql` is a program. It's the client for connecting to MySQL servers. You get it from http://www.mysql.com. If you're asking this, though, you probably don't know how to use it...? I don't know why you keep mentioning cpanel, your question doesn't have anything to do with some arbitrary web control panel software...

Comment: i know how to use `mysql`, in this problem I only got ftp connection on one wordpress website, I don't know what is the link for accessing the `mysql`.

Comment: Use your FTP client to download the `wp-config.php` file which has the database hostname and login info.

Comment: what is link exactly to the login page of mysql? :D assuming the link would be www.sampleURL.com

Comment: MySQL is a database server. There is no web interface to log in to. There is no link. You use the `mysql` client on your shell/command prompt to connect and issue queries. You said you knew how to use it.

Comment: @winona You're probably thinking of phpMyAdmin that comes with cPanel. It's a web interface to MySQL, but the site you're trying to reach probably doesn't have it. You have to use the plain MySQL client, and if you haven't used one before you need to put your studying hat on...